# Timerjob not executing

Tags: timer-jobs, timer-service

I got a Timerjob correctly scheduled in central admin. When i attach VS to the SharePoint timer service and "Run now" the timerjob from central admin, i notice several call the default constructor of my class inheriting from SPJobDefinition, and then, well, nothing. Execute() method is never called.

Why is that ?

EDIT : Because the override is `void Execute(Guid targetInstanceId)` and not `void Execute()`

Comment: Try to restart OWS process.
and use this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798310.aspx

Comment: Did you find a solution, I'm facing the same issue. Thanks.